# Retrieving timezone in pretty formatted git log output (format specifier)?

Tags: git, timezone

I'm trying to print out a git log with UTC/UNIX epoch seconds timestamp, timezone of commit, and short hash.

I have noticed https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log/2.17.1 :

> %ad: author date (format respects --date= option)
>
> %at: author date, UNIX timestamp
>
> - --date=raw shows the date as seconds since the epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC), followed by a space, and then the timezone as an offset from UTC (a + or - with four digits; the first two are hours, and the second two are minutes). I.e., as if the timestamp were formatted with `strftime("%s %z")`). Note that the -local option does not affect the seconds-since-epoch value (which is always measured in UTC), but does switch the accompanying timezone value.

So, I naively tried this first:

```
$ git --no-pager log --reverse --pretty='%at %z %h'
1528917616 %z 1cabbe9
1528960200 %z 3fad300
1528964789 %z ba4e746
1528964798 %z d39a4f8
...
```

Clearly, the `%z` doesn't expand within git log `--pretty`/`--format`.

Then, somewhat by accident, I tried this:

```
$ git --no-pager log --reverse --date=raw --pretty='%ad %h'
1528917616 +0000 1cabbe9
1528960200 +0000 3fad300
1528964789 +0000 ba4e746
1528964798 +0000 d39a4f8
1528967981 +0000 a9cdecb
1528970465 +0000 3e9cee9
....
```

... and that is exactly what I wanted! Except, here I don't have a separate format argument for the timezone, so I cannot move it elsewhere if I want to, at least not directly in the `git log` command.

So, does anyone know, if there is a format specifier that I could use directly in `git log`, and which will obtain me only the timezone of the timestamp of the commit?

Answer (score 1):

In `git log`, `--pretty` (or `--format`) does not have a placeholder for the timezone. But `--date=format:` does. It seems `--date=raw` is equivalent to `--date=format:"%s %z"`. So if you want only the timezone of a specific commit, you can try:

```
git log -1 <commit> --pretty=%ad --date=format:%z
```

Note that `%ad` is for author date. If you want commit date, use `%cd` instead. Besides, there are several placeholders for predefined date formats, like `%ai`, `%at`, `%cD`, etc. If any of these placeholders is used, `--date=format` is just ignored.